# Cannot continue program execution when throwing exception java

Tags: java, try-catch

I am practicing using the try-catch block to validate user input. Trying so hard to do but don't know why it doesn't work. I tried it both ways. It always pops out `InputMismatchException` and end the program.

The first one, I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWez5mVXACc&t=356s

```
public int moveStone(int initialStone, int upperBound, int stoneBalance) throws Exception {
    int takeStone = 0;
    boolean isNumber = false;

    do {
        if (in.hasNextInt()){
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            isNumber =true;
        } 
        if (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            if (stoneBalance >= upperBound) {
                System.out.println("Invalid move. You must remove between 1 and " + upperBound + " stones.\n");
                isNumber = false;
                takeStone = in.nextInt();
            }

            if (stoneBalance < upperBound) {
                System.out.println("Invalid move. You must remove between 1 and " + stoneBalance + " stones.\n");
                isNumber = false;
                takeStone = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
    } while (!(isNumber));
    return takeStone;
}
```

and this, I followed by other tutorials:

```
public int moveStone(int initialStone, int upperBound, int stoneBalance) throws Exception {
    int takeStone = 0;
    try {
        if (in.hasNextLine()) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            return takeStone;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid move");
        if (stoneBalance >= upperBound) {
            System.out.println("You must remove between 1 and " + upperBound + " stones.\n");
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            return takeStone;
        }

        if (stoneBalance < upperBound) {
            System.out.println("You must remove between 1 and " + stoneBalance + " stones.\n");
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            return takeStone;
        }
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us where the MismatchException occurs? Point out the line number of add the stacktrace?

Comment: when `in.hasNextInt()` executes. @L3n95

Comment: You are doing `in.nextInt()` event after checking that there is no next int `!in.hasNextInt()` and then the `in.nextInt()` throws the Exception because it can't find an `int`

Comment: yeah, just exchange it with else. @L3n95

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing `Exception`

```
if (in.hasNextLine()) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

And catching only `InputMismatchException`. Use `Exception` in `catch`

```
catch (Exception e){
```

Comment: I did it. It prints out `Invalid move...` and ` You must...` , and the program ends. Or it has something to do with other code? @Code_Mode

Comment: Of course it ends because it is end of your code :) If you use the above advice, you get into one of these two ifs and returns 0

Comment: I would suggest you go through docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: Sir, I just figured it out. It's simple but tricky. I wrote down the answer, and if you're interested, have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got where the problem is: **the user input still remains in the Scanner buffer.**

1. When it passes the invalid input, it goes to the catch block. This operation is correct.
2. However, when the program has to prompt the user to give another input, the invalid input still in the Scanner that it goes straight to the `takeStone = in.nextInt()`. The program jumps out because of `InputMismatchException` directly.

**The solution is to put another Scanner to take the token before prompting the user input.**

```
public int moveStone(int initialStone, int upperBound, int stoneBalance) throws Exception {
    int takeStone = 0;
    try {
        if (!in.hasNextInt()) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            return takeStone;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (stoneBalance >= upperBound) {
            System.out.println("Invalid move. You must remove between 1 and " + upperBound + " stones.\n");
            in.next(); // input still in the Scanner buffer, use another scanner to take this input
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            return takeStone;
        }

        if (stoneBalance < upperBound) {
            System.out.println("Invalid move. You must remove between 1 and " + stoneBalance + " stones.\n");
            in.next();
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
            return takeStone;
        }
    } 
    return -1;
}
```